# Beautifulsoup: how to iterate a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a dynamic table with the following structure:

Team 1 - Score - Team 2 - Minute first goal.

It is a table of soccer match results and there are about 10 matches per table and one table for each matchday. This is an example of the website in working with: https://www.resultados-futbol.com/premier/grupo1/jornada1

For this I am trying web scraping with BeautifulSoup in Python. Although I've made good progress, I'm running into a problem. I would like to generate a code that would iterate data by data each row of the table and I would get each data to a list so that I would have, for example:

```
List Team 1: Real Madrid, Barcelona
Score list: 1-0, 1-0
List Team 2: Atletico Madrid, Sevilla
First goal minutes list: 17', 64'
```

Once I have the lists, my intention is to make a complete dataframe with all the extracted data. However, I have the following problem: the matches that end 0-0. This implies that in the column Minute first goal there is none and it doesn't extract anything, so I can't 'fill' that value in any way in my dataframe and I get an error. To continue with the previous example, imagine that the second game has ended 0-0 and that in the 'Minutes first goal list' there is only one data (17').

In my mind the solution would be to create a loop that takes the data cell by cell and put a condition in 'Score' that if it is 0-0 to the list of Minutes first goal a value for example 'No goals' would be added.

This is the code I am using. I paste only the part in which I would like to create the loop:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') # I have to use Selenium previously cos I have to expand some buttons in the web
table = page.find('div', class_= 'contentitem').find_all('tr', class_= 'vevent')

teams1 = []
teams2 = []
scores = []

for cell in table:
    team1 = cell.find('td', class_='team1')
    for name in local:
        nteam1 = name.text
        teams1.append(nteam1)
        
    team2 = cell.find('td', class_='team2')
    for name in team2:
        nteam2 = name.text
        teams2.append(nteam2)
        
    score = cell.find('span', class_='clase')
    for name in score:
        nscore = name.text
        scores.append(nscore)
```

It is not clear to me how to iterate over the table to be able to store in the list the content of each cell and it is essential to include a condition "when the score cell is 0-0 create a non-goals entry in the list".

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful. Best regards

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what the html table looks like, and what does not work in your code ?

Comment: Could you improve your question and also add an expected output, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to your goal, but can optimize your script a bit.

1. Do not use these different `list`s, just use one:

   ```
   data = []
   ```
2. Try to get all information in one loop, there is an `td` that contains all the information and push a `dict` to your `list`:

   ```
   for row in soup.select('tr.vevent .rstd'):
       teams = row.select_one('.summary').get_text().split(' - ')
       score = row.select_one('.clase').get_text()

       data.append({
           'team1':teams[0],
           'team2':teams[1],
            'score': score if score != '0-0' else 'No goals'
        })
   ```
3. Push your data into `DataFrame`

   ```
    pd.DataFrame(data)
   ```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.resultados-futbol.com/premier/grupo1/jornada1'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') # I have to use Selenium previously cos I have to expand some buttons in the web

data = []

for row in soup.select('tr.vevent .rstd'):
    teams = row.select_one('.summary').get_text().split(' - ')
    score = row.select_one('.clase').get_text()
    
    data.append({
        'team1':teams[0],
        'team2':teams[1],
        'score': score if score != '0-0' else 'No goals'
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, HedgeHog. It works perfect!

Now I'm having a 'new' problem. If you see the web (https://www.resultados-futbol.com/premier/grupo1/jornada1) there are buttons to expand the events with the scorers and the minute of goals. I've seen the html and these events are in:

    tr.league-match-events

I'd like to get the first goal and the minute, only the data of the first row. But it doesn't work. I try to follow the same logical than the previous loop with select and select_one but it selects all the goals and minutes, not the info in the first row. Any suggestion?